# Change language in google maps after it was initialized

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have angular app which loads all the relevant resources on the initialization. One of the scripts is the Google maps v3. Our users can change language inside the web site, and I would like to prevent refreshing the entire site..
Is it possible to change only the language of the google maps?
maybe reloading only this scrip?

Please help
Ziv

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a function or property available that you can update on a map to set its language.  The language parameter you pass in via the URL to the script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=ja">
```

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Language

So what you could do is dynamically load in the map, e.g.

```
function updateMapLanguage(language) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3' +
        '&language=' + language + 
        '&callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#asynch

You'd probably also need something on your event listener for when they change the language, to remove the previous version of the map.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, This is how we load the  sources at first place. Do you have an example how can I reload them after the language has been changed?

Comment: So when the user changes the language, you should trigger a function like the example I gave.  Your callback function should load in the map, and possibly remove the previous one.

Comment: I didn't find how to remove the old version.. is there a way to do it?

Comment: I don't know how you'd do it with Angular. In jQuery, I'd just use the `remove()` function. There's probably a way in standard javascript to remove it from the DOM.